# What would be the logical approach in breaking down the following scenario in regard to CISSP Domains?

Tags: permissions, risk-management, regulation, cissp, pii

I'm currently doing my Cyber Security Certification program, I along with my fellow classmates are in Beginner stages. Over the past few weeks we have been writing up variety of Discussions using Domains 1 to 5, for this Week we are given a scenario and must utilize Domains 6 and 7. Where I have a strong grasp of Technical aspect I don't have such grasp in relation to Management aspect.

The Discussion scenario is as followed:

> A North American auto manufacturer has recently opened up a
> manufacturing plant within a country that is classified as an emerging
> economy. The key challenges that this North American auto manufacturer
> faces is that from a security and privacy perspective, this location
> does not carry the same stringent security and privacy requirements to
> that of North America. There are a number of missing regulations, no
> penalties for data breaches, and no government legislation or
> applicable law around the collection, usage, storage and dissemination
> of Personal Identifiable Information (PII).
>
> Using your knowledge from domain 6 and first half of domain 7, what
> additional detailed assessments, tests, and possible recommendations
> you would advise this North American auto manufacturer to exercise to
> ensure it does not degrade its existing stringent security and privacy
> practices (given there is no incentive to maintain it)?

For some odd reason this week's discussion is drawing blanks and I can't seem to grasp of what I should be Analyzing and what steps I should be taking. Do not get me wrong, I enjoy learning but somehow this particular scenario is drawing blanks. In part I don't exactly grasp the question. As such it would be appreciated if someone can help me break this scenario down in a more understandable format.

At this stage I gotten a few loose points:

> 1. Company A opened operations in Country B
> 2. Country B has lax/non-existing regulations. This should be considered. How much should this be used for decision weight?
> 3. Can Company A operate in Country B, but store all Data of Country B citizens/ect on Company A servers in Country A?
> 4. If Company A would account for Point 2 and 3, should Company A even consider this actions as financially viable?
> 5. If Point 4 is true, should Company A deploy same frameworks and policies as they use to operate in Country A while operating in
>    Country B and not being bound by much legal restrictions?

This is where I currently stand. I'm not sure how valid my points are, or if I'm even on the right path.

Feedback is appreciated.